# Is there a way to move a modal dialog?

Tags: macos

Some dialog boxes such as Save or Print cannot be dragged to a different place. I find it really annoying because often it’s useful to see the document underneath to help decide on the filename I want to use, whether that’s in the Save As dialog or within Print > Save as PDF.

Literally zero other people on Google seem to find this a problem, though there was a question on this site referring to the same thing in 2013. Nobody had an answer. Wondering if, 10 years later, anybody knows of any sneaky command line settings or third party tools?

Comment: Change your workflow to look at the document first, then Save/Print. Those *dialogs* (modals are on web pages)  can’t be moved because they need your full attention to complete the action.

Comment: …and sometimes you forget what it was you read so you have to cancel and start again. Instead of just moving the thing out the way